# Romans and Germans and such

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, geography

> My beginning is a halogen.
>   My middle is Roman.
>   My ending is Swedish.
>   My whole was Roman.
>
> My beginning is a dessert.
>   My middle is German.
>   My ending makes plurals.
>   My whole was German.

Answer is one word.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Fielding this:

> Flanders

My beginning is a halogen.  My middle is Roman. My ending is Swedish. My whole was Roman.

> **F** - Fluorine, **L** - Roman numeral 50, **Anders** - a Swedish name.
>
>  Flanders (Belgica) was a northern region of the Roman Empire - thanks due to Rudy Velthuis.

My beginning is a dessert. My middle is German. My ending makes plurals. My whole was German.

> **Flan** - a sponge based dessert, **der** - German definite article, **s** - added to pluralise.
>
>  Flanders was occupied by German forces in the Great War.

Comment: no problem, glad to help! Obligatory [Simpsons reference](https://memegenerator.net/instance/64038919/angry-homer-simpson-stupid-flanders)

Comment: Thanks @El-Guest and M Oehm - I needed help on German (at first I skipped a letter). (Apols for no credit but I've made so many edits on this you both are so renowned!)

Comment: Was it called that in times of Roman Empire?

Comment: At the time of the Roman Empire, it was called something like Belgica (the inhabitants were called Belgae). See Caesar's "De Bello Gallico", first few lines. And the word "Flanders" is not German, it is English. And it is Fluorine, not Flourine.

Comment: "Flour"ine LOLLOL

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

My beginning is a halogen.

> F, Cl, Br, I, or At

My middle is Roman.

> 

My ending is Swedish.

> 

My whole was Roman.

> 

My beginning is a dessert.

> 

My middle is German.

> 

My ending makes plurals.

> current thinking is 's'

My whole was German.

> 